# How can I redefine \int to put a negative space after the integral sign, but keep the limits properly set?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, kerning, integral

I'd like to modify the `\int` command such that it adds an automatic negative space, e.g. `\!` after the integral sign. Preferentially, I'd like to be able to not edit any of my code, so cleverly redefining `\int` seems like my best option. Unfortunately, naive implementations get the limits wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\diff}[2][]{
  \ifthenelse { \equal {#1} {} }
  {\ensuremath{\mathop{\mathrm{d} #2}}}
  {\ensuremath{\mathop{\mathrm{d}^#1 #2}}}
}

\begin{document}

This is what I would want:
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \mspace{-4mu}\diff[3]{\boldsymbol r} f(\boldsymbol r),
\end{equation}
but with this ``user code", containing no negative spacing explicitly:
\begin{verbatim}
 \int_0^\infty \diff[3]{\boldsymbol r} f(\boldsymbol r),
\end{verbatim}
which for comparison with the above gives:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \diff[3]{\boldsymbol r} f(\boldsymbol r),
\end{equation}

mostly because this gives me the option to remove it or change the spacing when I see fit.
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Note I can't put it in `\diff` because that command is used everywhere, and sometimes the integral sign is followed by a fraction containing the `\diff`...

Comment: Are you open to a wrapper command `\Integral` or something like this?

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Hmm that would take a lot of user code modification. I can write that myself, but asked here to see if there was a nice/hackish way to push that into `\int`.

Comment: The problem is the implicit `\limits` command which must be done first and then then negative spacing added

Comment: If you *always* add limits to the integral, it's easy, `\def\int_#1^#2{\oldint_{#1}^{#2} \mspace{-4mu}}`. In case you don't always have limits, it's a bit more trickier. In any case, let's see if someone comes with an “official” solution.

Comment: @Manuel that's halfway there, I didn't know that was possible. Exactly the reason I keep asking weird questions like this.

Comment: @Manuel: That's what I had in my mind too, but the case with `limits` is cumbersome

Comment: @Manuel: In the sense that I've got no clue how to do it ;-)

Comment: @Manuel: Sorry, I did not mean `\limits`, but the integration limits in general

Comment: I would like `\int` to still add `\limits` as well (I used the `intlimits` option to `amsmath` in my example, which does just that.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence If it's always input like `\int_{..}^{..}` then it's easy with the definition I did before. If not, with `\@ifnextchar` and a few auxiliar macros, or with `xparse`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

With this code

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*\diff[2][]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\ifblank{#1}{}{^{#1}}{#2}}}
\let\originalint\int
\def\int_#1^#2{\originalint_{#1}^{#2}\mathopen{}}
```

you remove space after the `\int` but your code must be written always with `\int_{..}^{..}` with limits and in that specific order. You could write some trickery so that if the limits are blank they are not added to the code. Or you could do some trickery with `\@ifnextchar` so that one checks for both limits in any order and the result is more clean. <strike>If it's wanted, I can add that</strike>. Here's the code (thanks to @kyle_the_hacker):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\diff[2][]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\ifblank{#1}{}{^{#1}}{#2}}}
\let\int@original\int
\def\int{\int@checkfirstsb}
\def\int@checkfirstsb{\@ifnextchar_{\int@checksecondsp}{\int@checkfirstsp}}
\def\int@checkfirstsp{\@ifnextchar^{\int@checksecondsb}{\int@{}{}}}
\def\int@checksecondsp_#1{\@ifnextchar^{\int@grabsp{#1}}{\int@{#1}{}}}
\def\int@checksecondsb^#1{\@ifnextchar_{\int@grabsb{#1}}{\int@{}{#1}}}
\def\int@grabsb#1_#2{\int@{#2}{#1}}
\def\int@grabsp#1^#2{\int@{#1}{#2}}
\def\int@#1#2{\int@original\ifblank{#1}{}{_{#1}}\ifblank{#2}{}{^{#2}}\mathopen{}}
\makeatother
```

In any case, here's an oportunity to add a bit of code I wrote some time ago to [add new kind of arguments to xparse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245419/21930).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_count_type_k:w #1
 {
  \__xparse_single_token_check:n { #1 }
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #1 { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
  \__xparse_count_mandatory:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_count_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__xparse_single_token_check:n { #1 }
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn { #2 } { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
  \__xparse_count_mandatory:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_type_k:w #1
 { \exp_args:NNo \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1 { \c__xparse_no_value_tl } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__xparse_flush_m_args:
  \__xparse_add_grabber_optional:N K
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__xparse_signature_tl { #1 { #2 } }
  \__xparse_prepare_signature:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_expandable_type_k:w #1
 {
  \exp_args:NNo \__xparse_add_expandable_type_K:w #1 { \c__xparse_no_value_tl }
 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__xparse_add_expandable_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { xparse } { invalid-expandable-argument-type } { K }
  \__xparse_add_expandable_type_m:w % May be create this?
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_trailing:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long_trailing:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {
  \exp_after:wN #4 \l__xparse_fn_tl ##1
   {
    \__xparse_add_arg:n { ##1 }
    #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
   }    
  \use:c { peek_meaning_remove #5 :NTF } #1
   { \l__xparse_fn_tl }
   {
    \__xparse_add_arg:n { #2 }
    #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
   }
 }

\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { a } { k \sb }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { b } { k \sp }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { A } { K \sb }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { B } { K \sp }

\NewDocumentCommand \diff { o m }
  {\mathop{\mathrm{d}\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}{#2}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\originalint\int
\RenewDocumentCommand \int { a b }
  {\originalint\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}\mathopen{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \diff[3]{\boldsymbol r} f(\boldsymbol r)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And it may be even better to check if `\diff` follows and in case it doesn't just have the original behaviour, just change the definition to this (it's a pity that spaces aren't skipped, so we need to explicitly check for a space and then check for `\diff` after that)

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand \int { a b t\@sptoken t\diff }
  {\originalint\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
   \IfBooleanT{#4}{\mathopen{}\diff}}
\makeatother
```

---

## After a few thoughts

Completed rethink code that I would use for a complete flexibility. This adds all possible combinations of sub-superscripts for the `\int` plus the *natural* input for differentials `\dd x`, `\dd{\bm x}`, `\dd^2 x`, `\dd^{a_1}{x_1}`.

```
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\dd{\@ifnextchar^{\dd@grabsp}{\dd@{}}}
\def\dd@grabsp^#1#2{\dd@{#1}{#2}}
\def\dd@#1#2{\mathop{d\ifblank{#1}{}{^{#1}}{#2}}}
\let\int@original\int
\def\int{\int@checkfirstsb}
\def\int@checkfirstsb{\@ifnextchar_{\int@checksecondsp}{\int@checkfirstsp}}
\def\int@checkfirstsp{\@ifnextchar^{\int@checksecondsb}{\int@{}{}}}
\def\int@checksecondsp_#1{\@ifnextchar^{\int@grabsp{#1}}{\int@{#1}{}}}
\def\int@checksecondsb^#1{\@ifnextchar_{\int@grabsb{#1}}{\int@{}{#1}}}
\def\int@grabsb#1_#2{\int@{#2}{#1}}
\def\int@grabsp#1^#2{\int@{#1}{#2}}
\def\int@#1#2{\int@original\ifblank{#1}{}{_{#1}}\ifblank{#2}{}{^{#2}}\mathopen{}}
\makeatother
```

that with the `xparse` code from before it would become

```
\NewDocumentCommand\dd{bm}{\mathop{d\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}{#2}}}
\let\originalint\int
\RenewDocumentCommand\int{ab}{\originalint\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}\mathopen{}}
```

Comment: I tried something like: `\makeatletter \let\originalint\int \def\int\@ifnextchar_{\@int}{\@int_{}^{}} \def\@int_#1^#2{\originalint_{#1}^{#2}\mathopen{}} \makeatother` but it don't work, could you add the correct way to do it to you answer? Thanks.

Comment: `\def\int{\@ifnextchar_{\@int}{\@int_{}^{}}}` at least there you got a missing pair of `{..}`.

Comment: Yeah, ok. That's because I tried a lot of stuff. I still become the error: You can't use `\spacefactor' in display math mode. (so obviously a problem with the @)

Comment: You are not using `\makeatletter`. This should compile fine `\makeatletter \let\originalint\int \def\int{\@ifnextchar_{\@int}{\@int_{}^{}}} \def\@int_#1^#2{\originalint_{#1}^{#2}\mathopen{}} \makeatother`

Comment: You are right, they were mispositioned. Edited your answer.

Comment: I rejected the edit. While it was correct, it's too simple. It is not what I intended to put there. I hope you don't mind; I added a complete solution (unless I made an error). It does work in all cases `\int \diff`, `\int_a \diff`, `\int^a \diff`, `\int_a^b \diff`, `\int^a_b \diff`.

Answer (score 2):

This has become really easy with the newest release of `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldint\int % for the comparison

\RenewDocumentCommand{\int}{e{_^}}{%
  \DOTSI
  \intop_{\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}^{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}%
  \mspace{-4mu}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\diff}{om}{% equivalent, but easier with xparse
  \mathop{\mathrm{d}\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}#2}
}

\begin{document}

This is the normal typesetting
\begin{equation}
 \oldint_0^\infty \diff[3]{\bm{r}} f(\bm{r}),
\end{equation}
This is what I would want:
\begin{equation}
 \oldint_0^\infty \mspace{-4mu}\diff[3]{\bm{r}} f(\bm{r}),
\end{equation}
and this is what we get
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \diff[3]{\bm{r}} f(\bm{r}),
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this is a false problem, mainly due to the spurious space inserted by the faulty definition of `\diff`.

Indeed, compare with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\diff}{om}{% note \!
  \mathop{\!\mathrm{d}\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}#2}
}

\begin{document}

This is the normal typesetting
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \diff[3]{\bm{r}} f(\bm{r}),
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the previously posted answer being ***HUGE*** and has complex dependencies, I tried to come up with a more compact solution, and arrived at the following:

### Code

Drop this anywhere in the document, before the first use of `\int`.

```
\makeatletter
\let\MyIntOrig\int
\def\MyIntSpace{\hspace{-.5em}} %% Configure as needed.
\def\int{\MyInt}
\def\MyInt{\MyIntOrig\MyIntSkipMaybe}
\def\MyIntSkipMaybe{
  \@ifnextchar_{\MyIntSkipScript}{%
  \@ifnextchar^{\MyIntSkipScript}{%
  \@ifnextchar\limits{\MyIntSkipTok}{%
  \@ifnextchar\nolimits{\MyIntSkipTok}{%
  %% Add more cases here as needed. Keep in mind to close the braces.
  \MyIntSpace}}}}%
}
\def\MyIntSkipScript#1#2{#1{#2}\MyIntSkipMaybe}
\def\MyIntSkipTok#1{#1\MyIntSkipMaybe}
\makeatother
```

### Minimal working document

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\MyIntOrig\int
\def\MyIntSpace{\hspace{-.5em}} %% Configure as needed.
\def\int{\MyInt}
\def\MyInt{\MyIntOrig\MyIntSkipMaybe}
\def\MyIntSkipMaybe{
  \@ifnextchar_{\MyIntSkipScript}{%
  \@ifnextchar^{\MyIntSkipScript}{%
  \@ifnextchar\limits{\MyIntSkipTok}{%
  \@ifnextchar\nolimits{\MyIntSkipTok}{%
  %% Add more cases here as needed. Keep in mind to close the braces.
  \MyIntSpace}}}}%
}
\def\MyIntSkipScript#1#2{#1{#2}\MyIntSkipMaybe}
\def\MyIntSkipTok#1{#1\MyIntSkipMaybe}
\makeatother


\def\MyTry#1{%
  & {\let\int\MyIntOrig #1} &
  & #1 &
  & \text{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}&
}
\begin{align*}
  & \text{Original} && \text{Redefined} && \text{Source} &\\
  \MyTry{\int }\\
  \MyTry{\int \int }\\
  \MyTry{\int a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int _b a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int ^c a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int _b^c a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int _{from}^{to} a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int \limits_{from}^{to} a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int \nolimits_{from}^{to} a\,dx}\\
  \MyTry{\int a_b x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```