# Use mathclap as default in limits of integration

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

I would like to change the default behaviour of `limits` to include `\mathclap`.

Rather than writing every time

```
\int\limits_{\mathclap{verylonglimit}} x \, dx
```

I would like to simply write

```
\int\limits_{verylonglimit} x \, dx
```

and to get the same behaviour.

I tried with (and similar forms) of:

```
\let\oldlimits\limits
\renewcommand{\limits_}[1]{\oldlimits_{\mathclap{#1}}}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to deal with the underscore.

Comment: you should almost never need to use explicit  `\limits` in a document

Comment: If you redefine `\limits` you will redefine `\stackrel`, `\buildrel`, `\doteq` and any other command that uses `\limits` internally.

Comment: What about `\int_{\mathclap{verylonglimit}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx`?

Comment: Two comments. (a) If you always need to place the lower (and upper) limits of integration above and below the integral symbol, you should load the `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) package with the option `intlimits`. (b) If typing `\mathclap` frequently is too tedious, just create a shortcut named, say, `\mc` to ease the job.

Comment: @Mico I know the ```intlimits``` option, but I still have to write every time the ```\mathclap``` part. Do you think the best option is to redefine and to use the shorthand?
@DavidCarlisle do you mean the same as @Mico? And yes, that redefine could be a problem.
@egreg still the same as @Mico? And in that case by using big integrands I could be in danger of an overlap between limits and integrands.
In general, is it possible to redefine a command comprising the underscore?

Comment: Depending on just how "tall" the integrand is, you may want to use a "big" (more precisely, a bigger than normal) integral symbol as well. See the posting [Big integral sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39181/5001) for more information on how to generate large integral symbols.

Comment: If you use `xparse` you can use the code from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245419/extending-xparse-for-new-arguments) to have `\let\originalint\int \NewDocumentCommand\int{b}{\originalint\limits\IfValueT{#2}{_{\mathclap{#2}}}}` and then use `\int_{whatever}` to act as `\int\limits_{\mathclap{whatever}}` (while you don't need to always input limits `\int f(x) \, dt` would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than redefine `\limits` -- which has the potential to cause lots of grief elsewhere in your document -- I'd like to suggest you define a new command called, say, `\mclimits` (short for "mathclap limits"...) as follows:

```
\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}
```

Note that with this definition, any use of `\mclimits` that doesn't employ the `_` character will result in a syntax error, as TeX will be scanning the input material for this character in order to "know" what's supposed to be macro's argument (the "`#1`" part). This constraint shouldn't be a problem in practice, since you'll *want* to use the `_` character in order to indicate the start of the material that should be placed in the lower-limit part of the full integral expression.

Here's the output of an MWE that uses the macro `\mclimits`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\int\mclimits_{\text{verylonglimit}}\! f(x)\,dx
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Leaving the issues obtained by redefining ```limits```, my problem was to deal with the underscore. I tried using ```def``` instead of ```renewcommand``` as in ```\let\oldlimits\limits
\def\limits_#1{\oldlimits_{\mathclap{#1}}}``` and it works. What I am missing?
Thinking to the possible side-effects, yes you are right, better to use a shorthand.

Comment: @Alex - With the TeX directive `\def`, it's possible to create a so-called "argument-delimited" macro, i.e., a macro whose argument is delimited by a specific symbol (such as `_`). Note that it's not possible (or, at least, not as easily possible) to do this with the LaTeX directives `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`.

Comment: I was not aware of that "argument-delimited" macro. Good to know (I should learn some more TeX). Thank you!

Comment: yes, this is the sensible approach.  but it could get you in big trouble if the expression with limits starts with two integral signs with separate lower limits.  in other words, it's not a "technique for all seasons".

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I didn't claim it was a "technique for all seasons", did I? :-) For sure, if either two consecutive integrals with lots of text in the lower limit or a very tall integrand occurs, the method will need to be adjusted.

Comment: @Mico -- no, you didn't claim that.  (and i know that *you* wouldn't do it.)  but too often i've seen techniques meant for a "local" fix be (mis)used in situations where they weren't appropriate.  so i get rather touchy on the subject.

Comment: @Alex after a definition such as `\def\limits_#1{..}` then any use of `\limits` (including existing commands that use it internally) that is not followed by `_` is a syntax error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Nicely put! I will add a sentence in my answer to stress the importance of not omitting `_` when using `\mclimits`.

Comment: @Mico yes although it's less of an issue for a new command of course, more of a danger if used with an existing one such as \limits

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not know If I got it clearly: by doing ```\def\limits_#1{..}``` can I only use ```\limits_``` while ```\limits``` has disappared? 
Thus, does redefining a macro using the same macro with the underscore make the original macro without the underscore disappear?

Comment: @Alex - The issue with redefining a macro (say, `\limits`, which doesn't take an argument by default) to take an argument *and* to include `_` as an argument delimiter is *not* that the macro itself somehow "disappears". Instead, it's the redefinition itself that may cause trouble. There are some useful LaTeX macros out there -- e.g., `\stackrel` and `\buildrel` -- that use `\limits` internally but don't use `_` -- and don't expect `\limits` to take an argument. If you redefine `\limits`, these macros will throw a syntax error, and it'll likely take you a long time to figure out the cause.

Comment: @Alex `\def\limits_` does not define a macro with name `limits_` it redefines the command with name `limits` such that it has to be followed by `_`  so `\limits_{1}` would be OK as would `\limits _ {1}` but `\limits^{1}` is an error.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem like an overkill… but that's how `xparse` works.

With the “complex code” what I do is define new type of `xparse` arguments, `k`, `K`, `a`, `b`, `A`, `B`. Being `a` and `A` the correspondent to subscripts. The others are explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245419/extending-xparse-for-new-arguments)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_count_type_k:w #1
 {
  \__xparse_single_token_check:n { #1 }
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #1 { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
  \__xparse_count_mandatory:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_count_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__xparse_single_token_check:n { #1 }
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn { #2 } { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
  \__xparse_count_mandatory:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_type_k:w #1
 { \exp_args:NNo \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1 { \c__xparse_no_value_tl } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__xparse_flush_m_args:
  \__xparse_add_grabber_optional:N K
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__xparse_signature_tl { #1 { #2 } }
  \__xparse_prepare_signature:N
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_add_expandable_type_k:w #1
 {
  \exp_args:NNo \__xparse_add_expandable_type_K:w #1 { \c__xparse_no_value_tl }
 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__xparse_add_expandable_type_K:w #1 #2
 {
  \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { xparse } { invalid-expandable-argument-type } { K }
  \__xparse_add_expandable_type_m:w % May be create this?
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_trailing:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long_trailing:w #1 #2 #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
 {
  \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 { #2 } { #3 } \cs_set_protected:Npn
   { _ignore_spaces }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_aux:NnnNn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {
  \exp_after:wN #4 \l__xparse_fn_tl ##1
   {
    \__xparse_add_arg:n { ##1 }
    #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
   }    
  \use:c { peek_meaning_remove #5 :NTF } #1
   { \l__xparse_fn_tl }
   {
    \__xparse_add_arg:n { #2 }
    #3 \l__xparse_args_tl
   }
 }

\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { a } { k \sb }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { b } { k \sp }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { A } { K \sb }
\prop_put:Nnn \c__xparse_shorthands_prop { B } { K \sp }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\originalint\int
\RenewDocumentCommand\int{ t\limits a }
 {\originalint\IfBooleanT{#1}{\limits}\IfValueT{#2}{_{\mathclap{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \int\limits_{verylonglimit} x \, dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I redefine the `\int` command first to gobble (and use) any `\limits` following it (if you want a different behaviour it can be changed, for instance if you want *all of them* to have `\limits` so `\int_a` would equal `\int\limits_{\mathclap{a}}`) then the command checks if there's a subscript like `_{whatever}` then pases `whatever` as second argument, we then pass it through a `_{\mathclap{#2}}` automatically.