# Xparse t argument type (underscore with optional parameter)

Tags: macros, xparse, optional-arguments

I am not understanding how to use the `t` type parameter with `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand`.

I am trying to define a macro that accepts one optional parameter, but the optional parameter is specified as a subscript using an underscore. That is I want to define something that behaves like

```
\def\MyMacro_#1{A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

but with the subscript being optional. I need `#1` to be parameter not simply a subscript added outside of the macro (i.e., `\MyMacro` must be the one that invokes the actual subscript)

The MWE below yields:

[image]

but the desired result is:

[image]

with the color and subscript applied by `\MyMacro`.

### Notes:

- The documentation states that `t` is

  > An optional ⟨token⟩, which will result in a value `\BooleanTrue` if ⟨token⟩ is present and `\BooleanFalse` otherwise. Given as t⟨token⟩.

  but no examples are given.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\newcommand*{\MyMacro}[1][]{}% Ensure we are not overwriting anything
%\def\MyMacro_#1{A_{\testcolor{red}{#1}}}% <-- Want this behavior but with the _{#1} being optional

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    }{%
        \mathbf{A}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$ 

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aren't you just trying to input `#1` -- which is `_` into `\textcolor`. Actually, your `_` must be followed by a second argument, which is `\pi` here

Comment: Related Question: [Extending xparse for new arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245419/extending-xparse-for-new-arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `t` argument specifier is a generalization of `s` that is the same as `t*`.

I don't think it's the right approach, but if you really want to go this way:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_}{A\IfBooleanT{#1}{\MyMacroAux}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacroAux}{m}{_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_}{A\IfBooleanT{#1}{\MyMacroAux}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacroAux}{m}{_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case the first part also depends on the presence of `_`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {A\MyMacroAux}
    {\mathbf{A}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacroAux}{m}{_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

Comment: What you would recommend as the right approach?

Comment: @PeterGrill A command for red subscripts, probably.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The actual use case is a bit more complicated, but agree that if all was trying to was to color the subscripts a specific macro to do that would be the right way.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like an `e`-type argument to me

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand\MyMacro{e_}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \mathbf{A}
    }{%
        A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$ 

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are adding `%` to those lines even in math mode, you are missing two :) I like that `k` has been implemented.

Comment: Works great, except that `k` is marked as _experimental_ so hesitant to use it at this time.

Comment: @PeterGrill Joseph is allowed to experiment with his own code though:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: :-). I just meant it as a reason that this was not the accepted answer.

Comment: The `k`-type works great when things get more complicated (such as having both `_` and `^` optional), so wondering when you think this will become non-experimental and be a permanent feature of `xparse`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I personally think this is probably going to stay. It's useful in general, and definitely now that there's no handling of super/sub-scripts. For me, ideally, in the future, apart from `k_ k^`, it might be good to have more automation in particular for math sub/super-scripts, like `i_ i^`  that will check for `\foo_{a}^{b}` but also for `\foo^{b}_{a}`. But `k` and `K` are definitely useful, and are (hopefully) going to stay.

Comment: It's down as experimental as there are some interface questions (we considered allowing a variable order of the type `k{_^}`, but this didn't quite feel right over all): what is needed is some testing/use cases. @Manuel The problem with allowing `k^k_` to be equal to `k_k^` was that it breaks the mapping between letters in the spec and the argument number, whilst allowing `k{_^}` has a similar concern. There's also the question of whether we really want to allow definitions emulating TeX primitive syntax (as TeX's parsing here is subtly different). One for LaTeX-L.

Comment: @JosephWright For me it's enough, and I think it's right, `k_ k^` (you can even tell the users that subscript go before superscripts), but I don't think it's too complex to map `i_ i^` so that `\foo_{a}^{b}` and `\foo^{b}_{a}` are read exactly the same (`#1=a` and `#2=b`). My point was to say to Peter that this is the way to go to solve this particular problem, at least this is the intended interface.

Comment: @Manuel This type of discussion is the reason the interface is down as experimental

Comment: It's been altered and renamed to `e`.  Now use `e{_^}` instead of the former `k_ k^`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch If we use `e{_^}` does that count as two arguments? Or just one with two optional tokens? How do we check to work depending of those optional tokens? I see the documentation has been updated and also accepts `{ m O{self referential #1} O{#2^2} }` I like that :)

Comment: @Manuel Currently as one: it's still experimental and we are still not sure what is best :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what is meant?

The `t_` check works, but `\textcolor{red}{#1}` will try to typeset `_` then, so `{\pi}` never enters the subscript.

In my opinion, the `{\pi}` is an 2nd optional argument. Either use `g` or the `G{}` type to grab this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\newcommand*{\MyMacro}[1][]{}% Ensure we are not overwriting anything
%\def\MyMacro_#1{A_{\testcolor{red}{#1}}}% <-- Want this behavior but with the _{#1} being optional

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_G{}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    A_{\textcolor{red}{#2}}
  }{%
    \mathbf{A}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$ 

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep that worlds fork the given MW.  However, I tend to avoid trailing optional parameters as they have issues if there are extra spaces. Example `$\MyMacro _ {\pi}$` fails with the use `G`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Well, the given MW was too minimal then, wasn't it? ;-)

Comment: :-) It was a TMWE.