# Passing an argument to a \newcommand as a subscript

Tags: macros

As I understand I can define new commands using

```
\newcommand{name}[num]{definition}
```

An example is

```
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbf{E}_{#1}}
```

Now I can use this in my text as follows

```
\E{\theta}
```

to print `\mathbf{E}_\theta`

Is it possible to pass the argument as a subscript instead of coding it between braces?

I would like to code it as

```
\E_\theta
```

which is more natural for me. I would also like to add a second argument so that I get

```
\mathbf{E}_\theta[X]
```

by coding it with

```
\E_\theta{X}
```

Comment: One option is to define `\newcommand\E{\mathbf{E}}` and then use `\E_\theta` and `\E_\theta[X]`. This said, I'd probably use `\newcommand\bE{\mathbf{E}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I would like to know how to pass an argument to a new command as a subscript. the example that I gave in the question is very simple and is only for illustration.

Comment: Short answer: See delimited arguments in the `xparse` manual. But use them with caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big fan of the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package but I do not know how to use it to do what you want because it uses *pairs* of deliminators for (optional) arguments. **EDIT** *Egreg's post [Xparse's new e-type argument (replacement for k-type argument)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345365/xparses-new-e-type-argument-replacement-for-k-type-argument) describes how to use [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to do this.*

You can do this easily enough using `\def` and `\@ifnextchar` to test for a bracket -- the definitions need to be surrounded in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because of the `@` in `\@ifnextchar`.

More explicitly, I think that the following pair of macros do what you want:

```
\def\E_#1{\mathbf{E}_{#1}\@ifnextchar[{\Ebrac}{\relax}}
\def\Ebrac[#1]{#1}
```

The definition of `\E` says that it has one argument that follows an underscore. This macros then uses `\@ifnextchar[`  to call `\Ebrac` if the next character is a bracket.

Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\E_#1{\mathbf{E}_{#1}\@ifnextchar[{\Ebrac}{\relax}}
\def\Ebrac[#1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\E_1, \E_\theta, \E_{\theta+1}$

$\E_1[X], \E_\theta[X], \E_{\theta+1}[X]$

\end{document}
```

This produces the output:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the thread I linked to?

Comment: @egreg No. I'll take a look now!

Comment: @egreg That's pretty cool. The `e`-type arguments are not mentioned in the documentation that I have for `xparse`...although the `k`-type arguments are but some how I missed them. Thanks.

Comment: Update your TeX distribution