# Measure spacing of \int

Tags: width, integral

I would like to be able to measure the space taken up by an `\int` and have that length stored in a `\newlength{}`. It is not as easy as

```
\settowidth{\@IntWidth}{\widthof{$\int$}}
```

In the MWE below, I attempt to apply a negative `\kern` of the measured spacing and redraw the symbol in red.  If the measuring was done correctly, the red symbol should be exactly on top of the black symbol, but I get:

[image]

### Notes:

- This ONLY address the case where there is both an upper and lower limit given, so the code that deals with the other options is commented out.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}%

\makeatletter
\let\OldIntOp\int
\newlength{\@IntWidth}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345383/4301
\RenewDocumentCommand\int{e{_^}}{% underscore ALWAYS before ^
  %\IfNoValueTF{#2}{% No upper limit
  %  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% No lower and upper limit
  %    \OldIntOp
  %  }{% Only lower limit
  %    \OldIntOp_{#1}
  %  }
  %}{
  %  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% No lower, but do have upper limit
  %    \OldIntOp^{#2}
  %  }{% Both lower and upper limit
      \OldIntOp
      \settowidth{\@IntWidth}{\widthof{$\OldIntOp$}}% ????? How compute this ??????
      \kern-\@IntWidth
      {\color{red} \OldIntOp_{#1}^{#2}}
  % }
  %}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
In inline math $\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldIntOp^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}
In inline math $\int_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\int^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the problem to typeset only the integral sign red? I'm not sure I understand your aim

Comment: @egreg: Am trying to detach the placement of the limits of integration from the placement of the actual integral symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about what you want to get. Anyway, the width can be computed with `\mathpalette` (there's also a `\!` to add and most likely some `\mathop` trickery).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}%

\makeatletter
\let\OldIntOp\int

\newcommand\kernint{\mathpalette\@kernint\relax}
\newcommand\@kernint[2]{%
  \!\sbox0{$\m@th#1\OldIntOp$}\kern-\wd0
}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345383/4301
\RenewDocumentCommand\int{e{_^}}{% underscore ALWAYS before ^
  %\IfNoValueTF{#2}{% No upper limit
  %  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% No lower and upper limit
  %    \OldIntOp
  %  }{% Only lower limit
  %    \OldIntOp_{#1}
  %  }
  %}{
  %  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% No lower, but do have upper limit
  %    \OldIntOp^{#2}
  %  }{% Both lower and upper limit
      \OldIntOp\kernint
      {\color{red} \OldIntOp_{#1}^{#2}}
  % }
  %}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
In inline math $\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldIntOp^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}
In inline math $\int_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\int^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
In inline math $\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\OldIntOp^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\OldIntOp_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}
In inline math $\int_a^b  y\dx$, and in display math it is:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\displaystyle\int^b_a  y\dx
    \textstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    \scriptscriptstyle\int_a^b  y\dx
    &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the actual measurements of the math box, the following example measures the math formula and writes its dimensions to the `.aux` file.
This works around a limitation of `\mathpalette`/`\mathchoice` that set the formula in all math styles, but TeX decides much later, which version it will use
(thanks to `\over` and friends).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\makeatletter

% Create new label type for the .aux file that takes
% the measurements of the math box.
% LaTeX takes care of re-run warnings Because of the usage of \@newl@bel.
\usepackage{auxhook}
\AddLineBeginAux{%
  \string\providecommand\string\New@MeasureMathBox[2]{}%
}
\newcommand*{\New@MeasureMathBox}{%
  \@newl@bel{mmb}%
}

% Counter for identifying a math box
\newcounter{MeasureMathBox}
\renewcommand*{\theMeasureMathBox}{\the\value{MeasureMathBox}}

% Register that contain the measurement result
\newdimen\LastMathBoxWidth
\newdimen\LastMathBoxHeight
\newdimen\LastMathBoxDepth

% Measure the math box and write the label
% with the measurements to the .aux file
% in all styles via \mathpalette.
% When TeX later decides, which box it uses,
% only one write command of the correct
% math style remains.
\newcommand*{\MeasureMathBox}{%
  % #1: math formula to be measured
  % New identifier for the math box.
  \stepcounter{MeasureMathBox}%
  % Read the label if available.
  \@ifundefined{mmb@\theMeasureMathBox}{%
    \LastMathBoxWidth\z@
    \LastMathBoxHeight\z@
    \LastMathBoxDepth\z@
  }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \Extract@MeasureMathBox
    \csname mmb@\theMeasureMathBox\endcsname\@nil
  }%
  \mathpalette\@MeasureMathBox
}
\def\Extract@MeasureMathBox#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \LastMathBoxWidth#1\relax
  \LastMathBoxHeight#2\relax
  \LastMathBoxDepth#3\relax
}
\newcommand*{\@MeasureMathBox}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: math formula to be measured
  % Do the actual measurement.
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2\m@th$}%
  % Write the label to the .aux file.
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\New@MeasureMathBox
    {\theMeasureMathBox}%
    {\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\Test{
  \int
  \MeasureMathBox{\int}
  \kern-\LastMathBoxWidth
  \! % negate horizontal spacing between two operators
  \begingroup\color{red} \int_a^b \endgroup y\diff x
}
\[ \Test \]
\[ \textstyle \Test \]
\[ \scriptstyle \Test \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle \Test \]
\end{document}
```

After the first compile run, the `.aux` file contains:

```
\relax
\providecommand\New@MeasureMathBox[2]{}
\New@MeasureMathBox{1}{10.00002pt,13.61122pt,8.61124pt}
\New@MeasureMathBox{2}{6.66667pt,8.0556pt,3.05562pt}
\New@MeasureMathBox{3}{6.66667pt,7.3056pt,3.80562pt}
\New@MeasureMathBox{4}{6.66667pt,6.8056pt,4.30562pt}
```

This is used in the second compile run:

> [image: Result]

If you are only interested in inserting the negative space of a math formula, the following works in one compile run (similar to egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434271/16967), but more general):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NegMathWidth}{%
  % #1: math formula to be measured
  \mathpalette{\@NegMathWidth}%
}
\newcommand*{\@NegMathWidth}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: math formula to be measured
  \settowidth\dimen@{$#1#2\m@th$}%
  \kern-\dimen@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\Test{
  \int
  \NegMathWidth{\int}
  \! % negate horizontal spacing between two operators
  \begingroup\color{red} \int_a^b \endgroup y\diff x
}
\[ \Test \]
\[ \textstyle \Test \]
\[ \scriptstyle \Test \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle \Test \]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.