# xparse xstring error while compiling LaTeX document

Tags: expl3

`! LaTeX3 Error: Unknown argument type 'k' for the command while typesetting the document. the command used is \command**{\cmd}{\oldcmd}{\lparen\rparen}`

The definition is

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewMathFun}{ssmmm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    \expandafter\let\csname OP\CsToStr{#3}\endcsname#4%
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\expandafter*\csname OP\CsToStr{#3}\endcsname{#4}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname OP\CsToStr{#3}\endcsname{#4}%
    }%
  }
  \NewDocumentCommand{#3}{ s k_ k^ k@ > {\SplitArgument{1}{}} D<>{#5} o}{%
    \csname OP\CsToStr{#3}\endcsname\IfNoValueF{##2}{_{##2}}\IfNoValueF{##3}{^{##3}}%
    \IfNoValueTF{##6}%
      {}%
      {\NewMathFunInternal{##1}##5{##6}\IfNoValueF{##4}{{##4}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\let\OLDdim\dim
\let\dim\undefined
\NewMathFun**{\dim}{\OLDdim}{\lparen\rparen}
```

Comment: For some time `xparse` provided an experimental `k` argument type, then superseded by the `e` argument type. Please, show the faulty definition and we can help in fixing it.

Comment: Thanks. I am adding the definition below:

Comment: is that a definition that you just wrote (in which case you are using old documentation) or is it in a package from ctan (in which case it needs updating) ?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what `\NewMathFun` is supposed to do.

Comment: The details on the switch from `k` to `e` type arguments is discussed in [Xparse's new e-type argument (replacement for k-type argument)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345365/4301).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle its part of the article submitted for typesetting, having trouble in processing the same.

Comment: @egreg Same here

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks will have alook at it

Comment: Thanks @Marijn for editing the code

Comment: Thanks @PeterGrill I was able to successfully compile the document by merely changing all k's to e's. It just dawned on me that I am outdated in LaTeX. Going thru expl3, interface3, xparse, xstring, etc. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @Senthil Is your problem solved? Can we close this question?

Comment: @siracusa Yes, the problem is resolved. The question can be closed. The resolution was done by replacing all "k" with an "e" argument type.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments