# incompatibility of xparse e- and t-type argument with subscriptcorrection option of newtxmath

Tags: subscripts, xparse, catcodes, newtxmath

It appears that the `subscriptcorrection` option for [newtxmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) is incompatible with e- and t-type arguments of [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) that use `_`. Using examples adapted from egreg's answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345365/xparses-new-e-type-argument-replacement-for-k-type-argument/345383#345383) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319304/xparse-t-argument-type-underscore-with-optional-parameter), the following compiles as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_}{A\IfBooleanT{#1}{\MyMacroAux}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacroAux}{m}{_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyOtherMacro}{e_}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\mathbf{A}}
        {A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
    }

\begin{document}
\textbf{t-type:} With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$

\textbf{e-type:} With a subscript: $\MyOtherMacro_{\pi}$

Without any subscript: $\MyOtherMacro$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However with `subscriptcorrection` enabled, the same code compiles without error but the macros have no effect:

[image]

The following lines in newtxmath.sty that are enabled by the package option suggest this is a catcode issue:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\_=\string"8000 \catcode`\_=12\relax} \begingroup
 \catcode`\_=13
 \gdef_{\expandafter\s@@b@}
\endgroup
```

I know that `` \catcode`\_=13 `` makes `_` an active character, but I've not been able to determine how this interacts with xparse's definition of e- or t-type commands. Is there a workaround to get the effect of `subscriptcorrection` while also having e- and t-type commands function as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xparse` requires that the token used in a `t` or `e` argument be identical to the one found when executing the command, which means its catcode and charcode have to both match.

The part of `subscriptcorrection` that makes your command not work is
`` \AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12\relax} ``, which makes the underscore an other (catcode 12) character at `\begin{document}`, but in the preamble, where you define your command, the underscore is still catcode 7, and this is the meaning of `_` that is fixed in your commands.

You can work around that by temporarily making the underscore catcode 12 while you define your commands:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\_=12
  \long\def\next#1{\endgroup#1}%
\next{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{t_}{A\IfBooleanT{#1}{\MyMacroAux}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacroAux}{m}{_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyOtherMacro}{e_}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\mathbf{A}}
        {A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\textbf{t-type:} With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$

\textbf{e-type:} With a subscript: $\MyOtherMacro_{\pi}$

Without any subscript: $\MyOtherMacro$
\end{document}
```