# Awkward spacing for integral in exponent

Tags: spacing, integral

I'm trying to put an integral in an exponent with the following LaTeX:

```
\begin{align*}
    e^{G(t)} &= e^{\int{\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt}} \\
    &= e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)} \\
    &= \sqrt{1 + t^2}
\end{align*}
```

however, the result is this:

[image: awkward spacing]

the spacing between the integral and the fraction looks very awkward. I looked into display mode, but that just makes the integral abnormally large. Is there anyway to get rid of that spacing?

Comment: I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233817/120578, this: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10000 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437423/latex-puts-too-much-space-next-to-integrals on this particular problem...

Comment: As an aside, `\int{...}` doesn't really make sense: `\int` is just a symbol (technically a `\mathop`), it doesn't take arguments.

Comment: @koleygr Ah, I did searches specifically for integrals in exponents, but maybe it would've been smarter for me to search more generally...

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Yeah, I just thought the spacing could possibly go away with the `\int{...}` but I was wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
e^{G(t)} &= e^{\int\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt} \\ % original
e^{G(t)} &= e^{\int\!\frac{t}{1+t^2}\,dt} \\
e^{G(t)} &= \exp\Bigl(\int\frac{t}{1+t^2}\,dt\Bigr) \\
e^{G(t)} &= \exp\bigl({\textstyle\int\frac{t}{1+t^2}\,dt}\bigr) \\
         &= e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)} \\
         &= \sqrt{1 + t^2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\!` seems to move it enough to not annoy me, thank you! Unrelated, is `\exp` an acceptable alternative to `e^n`? I've never seen that notation before.

Comment: @ryanyz10: `\exp(...)` for `e^{...}` is quite standard.

Answer (score 8):

Does this befit you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    e^{G(t)} &= e^{\int{\mkern-7mu\frac{t}{1+t^{\scalebox{0.8}{$ \scriptscriptstyle2 $}}} dt}} \\
    &= e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)} \\
    &= \sqrt{1 + t^2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: thanks. Still I hope my proposition is not totally unworthy :–)

Comment: I like either anwers of Bernard and egreg. I vote always your answer. Too for Mico and marmot. +1.