# How to kern kpfont integrals?

Tags: mathtools, kerning, kpfonts, integral

`kpfont` integrals have a lot of empty space both on the left and on the right ever with `smashoperator`:

[image]

How do I kern the function "into" the integral and reduce the white space of the left document-wide?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intlimits]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}} f(t) dt
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
SMOP = \smashoperator{\int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}}} f(t) dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a partial solution in [How can I redefine \int to put a negative space after the integral sign, but keep the limits properly set?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233817/how-can-i-redefine-int-to-put-a-negative-space-after-the-integral-sign-but-kee)

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\int}{e{_^}}{%
  \DOTSI
  \intop_{\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}^{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}%
  \mspace{-4mu}%
}
```